# How to restrict copy paste in text-filed for iOS App in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift

In my application i am trying to restrict copy and paste from text-filed. Is there any  default/better way to do this in Swift5?

tried using below code but not working

```
var key: Void?

class UITextFieldAdditions: NSObject {
    var readonly: Bool = false
}

extension UITextField {
    var readonly: Bool {
        get {
           return self.getAdditions().readonly
     } set {
        self.getAdditions().readonly = newValue
    }
}

private func getAdditions() -> UITextFieldAdditions {
    var additions = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key) as? UITextFieldAdditions
    if additions == nil {
        additions = UITextFieldAdditions()
        objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, additions!, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
    }
    return additions!
}

open override func target(forAction action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Any? {
    if ((action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) || (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.cut(_:)))) && self.readonly) {
        return nil
    }
    return super.target(forAction: action, withSender: sender)
}

}
```

Comment: @ElTomato I have read that answer then only asking question..Please suggest answer than duplicating because given answers are not working for me

Comment: See Nikhil Manapure's solution.

Comment: @ElTomato also in other question not answer is accepted..and has many answers which are really old and not working for Swift 5

Comment: I have tested Nikhil Manapure's solution there personally under Swift 5.

Comment: @ElTomato do I need to subclass textfiled ?

Comment: @ElTomato will this work for textview also?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension to `UITextField` to hide *Copy* and *Paste* action:

```
extension UITextField {
    override open func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        return (action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.copy(_:))
            || action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:))) ?
            false : super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: He wants to disable not just Paste but Copy and Paste.

Comment: Thanks for answer..Do i need to create any delegate for textfield.  coz after using this also i am able to copy and paste

Comment: I edited for *copy* also. Just overriding this delegate should work.

Comment: I've tested it myself.  I don't think your solution works.

Comment: I am testing on simulator and still able to copy paste text in textfiled ..am i missing anything?

Comment: @omerfarukozturk are you testing on device? or is this issue because i am testing on simulator with laptop keyboard?

Comment: I've tested for a single UITextField in simulator and added screenshots. I am override only this delegate for textfield.

Comment: i did txtZipCode.delegate =  self in viewdidload ..is this correct or need to to anything else too?

Comment: I see.  It doesn't work on the Simulator but works on an actual device.

Comment: @SandeshSardar Adding extension to UITextField not related to setting a delegate. You can try removing  your current implementation as you wrote in question `open override func target(forAction action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Any?` or you can write a custom class that inherits from UITextField.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk tried this extension but somehow i am able to copy paste in simulator .. using xcode 11.4 and iOS 13 iPhone 11(simulator)

Comment: Did you debug it that new delegate works? You should remove your `func target(forAction..` delegate and add `func canPerformAction(_ action..`

Comment: yes..extension method is not getting called

Comment: @omerfarukozturk will this work for textview also..means same method but for textview extension

Comment: Yes it should work both. I suggest you to create a new project and add only a UITextField and this delegate, and try it. I am not sure what is the issue you get.